# how to make the text shadow next to the real text so it looks like duplicated text in css?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm creating marquee. These are the steps:
[image][image][image]
To do that I have to make a `text-shadow` next to the original text. The problem is the text width is not constant so I can do something like:

```
...{
  text-shadow: 619px 0 0 black;
}
```

this is my code:

```css
.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 619px 0 0 black;
}

.marquee>* {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <h1>lorem ipsum dolor ist as ment lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

NOTE: I know I can get the width of the text and set the shadow depending on it in JavaScript.

Comment: The problem isn't clear to me. "The problem is the text width is not constant so I can do something like" - What do you mean by text-width? Can you provide a few more details on desired end-result?

Comment: @Kameron if they change the text by adding/removing words, they also have to change the value of _offset-x_ of the text-shadow. The question is about how to set the shadow in CSS without the need to know in advance how much text is contained inside the marquee element

Comment: Short answer: **this is not possible**. CSS cannot pull in a calculated dynamic width of another class/element. Or in other words, you cannot use the `width` property of the `<h1>` as a value for any other property using pure CSS. If the width of the text exceeds the width of the container, you will need something other than CSS to make this possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this with html [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and css [after pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Just duplicate the text inside the `h1` tag to `data-text` attribute.

```css
.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.marquee > h1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  will-change: transform;
}

h1::after {
  /* this is where you will use the data-attribute */
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <h1 data-text="lorem ipsum dolor ist as ment lorem ipsum">lorem ipsum dolor ist as ment lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```